# Vector Declaration

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am new to STL and I cannot understand this strange behavior of vector.
While writing a code for a question I used two type of declarations for vector of `pair<int,int>`.

First:

```
int n,m; 
cin>>n>>m;
vector<pair<int,int> > v[n*m];
```

Second:

```
int n,m,size;
cin>>n>>m; 
size=n*m;
vector<pair<int,int> > v[size];
```

If observed that the first one was not giving the required result whereas the second type gave me the correct result.

Is there any difference between these two types. If yes, What is the difference?

Comment: You're creating a raw array of `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>` of size `n*m` and `size` respectively. You probably don't want this.

Comment: Neither example is standard C++, since you cannot declare an array using a runtime value to determine the number of items.  [See this](http://rextester.com/EAVG29207)

Comment: Try to have a look at the preview of your post when asking a question. @NathanOliver kindly edited your post using code blocks but before it was barely readable due to the use of `<` and `>` outside code blocks (which were interpreted as HTML tags).

Comment: @erip thank you for the answer. I basically want an array whose each block is a vector into which I can insert pair.But, I just couldn't figure out why they were behaving differently in both the cases...

Answer (score 1):

None of these should work (or even compile) because your are declaring a local array with "dynamic" (runtime) size:

```
size_t x = 34;
int y[x]; // Error!
```

What your code does is declaring an array containing `K` vectors (`vector<pair<int,int>>`), while what you probably want is a vector of size `K`:

```
int n, m;
cin >> n >> m; 
vector<pair<int,int> > v(n * m);
```

Comment: While what you say is true, why should there be a difference between the two on platforms that support VLAs as an extension?

Comment: @Holt I have tried both the codes and they are working, but I just couldn't figure out the difference between both of these.I used online Ideone compiler with C++14.@PaulMcKenzie